# having trouble with jquery collapsible plugin

Tags: jquery, collapsable

I am having trouble to get the script to execute. I am utilizing jquery collapsible plugin.

http://jsfiddle.net/VzqJK/46/

Can someone help me identify what the issue is?

For some reason when pasting the code in jsfiddle, it is now working.
But what I am trying to achieve is

1. Have a default item to be open or active by default
2. When expanding an item, all other items are collapsed
3. When expanding an item and loading a sub menu item, it retains its current state.

**ex:**

parent 1
parent 2
--child a
--child b
parent 3
--child c

if i click on child b, it applies a '`class=current`' to child b's  tag and applies '`class=active`' to parent 2 `<li> tag`.

Your help is much appreciated in this matter.

Thanks!

RD

Comment: Should that be _not_ working?

Comment: Error in your fiddle: TypeError: $(...).collapsible is not a function

Comment: In the fiddle you need to put your jQuery code _after_ the plugin code in the JavaScript pane

Comment: sorry everyone, this is now resolved. This is now updated. Thanks andyb.
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/VzqJK/45/)

I am still looking for help on achieving 1, 2, and 3 though.

Answer (score 0):

The [api](http://www.snyderplace.com/demos/collapsible.html) provides `defaultOpen: '',` for selecting which elements are open on load.  You may need to switch to the Accordion plugin for #2, or write some custom code. I'm not really sure what #3 is about.